# Backup gets started twice Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, backup

After using Magento for some time I came across some strange behavior: If I make a database backup (system / tools / backup) under some conditions the backup will be started twice:

If I type in the backup name and hit the enter key on the keyboard I get 2 backups in the var/backups folder (also listed on the backup site in the backend). If I use the mouse and click the OK button I get only one backup.

I watched this now for some time and it seems as if this is repeatable. Since the backup needs some time this is a little bit uncomfortable especially because the shop is offline for this time.

Has anyone seen this behavior too and does somebody know the reason or a solution to prevent this ?

Thanks

Comment: any specific browser you are using? I tried on FF and Chrome and cannot reproduce it